# Размещение background css

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image]

Как разместить два background для одного div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2014/02/27/16/10/tree-276014__340.jpg),
                    url(https://images.ctfassets.net/hrltx12pl8hq/4plHDVeTkWuFMihxQnzBSb/aea2f06d675c3d710d095306e377382f/shutterstock_554314555_copy.jpg);
  background-position: right top, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-size: 50% auto, 100% auto;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```